# Java - If statement scope variable

Tags: java, spring, if-statement

I have a problem with the scope when I'm using the *if statement*... I can't get the value from inside *if else*. The object has a null value in the *message* variable.

Class

```
public class UserMessage{
    String message;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userMessage")
public @ResponseBody UserMessage getMessage(Principal principal){
    String username = principal.getName();

    UserMessage userMessage = new UserMessage();

    if(username.equals("admin")){
        //Set value to "message" variable
        userMessage.setMessage("Hi admin!")
    }

    else 
    if (username.equals("seller")) {
        //Set value to "message" variable
        userMessage.setMessage("Hi seller!")
    }

    else 
    if (username.equals("customer")) {
        //Set value to "message" variable
        userMessage.setMessage("Hi customer!")
    } 

    // This object has a null value in the message variable.
    return userMessage;

}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Um, what's the actual `username` value?

Comment: Please show code for the UserMessage methods, especially setMessage() and whatever you are using to see the message is null.

Comment: The problem must be with in the set message method

Comment: @RamanSB Or `username` is anything other than "admin", "seller", or "customer" so setMessage() is never called.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes you are correct, I agree.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan nailed it. If OP would kindly check the actual `username` value s/he'll see it is an unexpected value.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan  The username doesn't really matter, it is only a parameter... The main problem is try to get the "message" variable with its new value out of "if" condition... An the end of the method the userMessage object return a null value because I can't get the message variable from inside the "If". This is a problem with the scope (I guess).

Comment: @wilson Have you tested making sure both that you have a correct setMessage method and that the name is one of the ones that will cause a setMessage call?

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting is masking the problem a wee bit:  there is the case in which `username` does not exactly equal any of these strings:

- `"admin"`
- `"seller"`
- `"customer"`

The reason is simple:  you don't have an `else` condition with the long chain of `if`-statements.

```
if (username.equals("admin")) {
    //Set value to "message" variable
    userMessage.setMessage("Hi admin!")
} else if (username.equals("seller")) {
    //Set value to "message" variable
    userMessage.setMessage("Hi seller!")
} else if (username.equals("customer")) {
    //Set value to "message" variable
    userMessage.setMessage("Hi customer!")
}
```

If you absolutely need a value for it, then set it to some sensible default; otherwise, consider making your `equals` statements case insensitive instead, if the casing of `username` could be slightly off (`"Admin"` instead of `"admin"`, etc).

```
// Also, flip the order of your equals so you don't run into silly NPEs
if("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(username))
```

It'd be beneficial for you to log the value of `username` out in at least DEBUG or TRACE until you can figure out why the value doesn't come in a form that you anticipate.

Comment: It sounds good but the other part of the problem is try to get the value out of  the "if" condition... As yo can see the userMessage object return a null value in the "message" variable. The main problem is that, I can't get the value out of the "if" condition. Do you know how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a default else clause to troubleshoot the issue:

```
else {
    userMessage.setMessage("Hi " + username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple test application based on your code. The output is:

```
name: admin message: Hi admin!
name: xyzzy message: null
```

As indicated in [Makoto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32419229/1798593), if you run your `if` structure with one of the username values that cause a setMessage call, the message is set, and there is no problem retrieving it from outside the `if`. If you run the if structure with any other username value, you do not call setMessage, and the message retains its initial, null, value.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] main) {
    testit("admin");
    testit("xyzzy");
  }

  private static void testit(String name) {
    UserMessage message = getMessage(name);
    System.out.println("name: " + name + " message: " + message.getMessage());
  }

  public static UserMessage getMessage(String username) {
    UserMessage userMessage = new UserMessage();

    if (username.equals("admin")) {
      // Set value to "message" variable
      userMessage.setMessage("Hi admin!");
    }

    else if (username.equals("seller")) {
      // Set value to "message" variable
      userMessage.setMessage("Hi seller!");
    }

    else if (username.equals("customer")) {
      // Set value to "message" variable
      userMessage.setMessage("Hi customer!");
    }

    // This object has a null value in the message variable.
    return userMessage;

  }
}

class UserMessage {
  String message;

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

}
```